# setting spring.profiles.active in OS X

Tags: ios, spring, macos, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to set the variable spring.profiles.active in order to create a package from the command line accordingly, but I don't know how to do it

```
MacBook-Pro-de-nunito:tdk calzada$ export spring.profiles.active=war,pebloc
-bash: export: `spring.profiles.active=war,pebloc': not a valid identifier
```

I have also another one

```
MacBook-Pro-de-nunito:tdk calzada$ export APP-KEY=pebloc
-bash: export: `APP-KEY=pebloc': not a valid identifier
```

After trying the proposed solution, the active profiles are empty

```
MacBook-Pro-de-nunito:tdk calzada$ export SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVE=war,sebloc
MacBook-Pro-de-nunito:tdk calzada$ mvn help:active-profiles
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.tdk:tdk:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 70, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tdk 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:active-profiles (default-cli) @ tdk ---
[INFO] 
Active Profiles for Project 'com.tdk:tdk:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT': 

The following profiles are active:




[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.491 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-15T19:23:01+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Replace `.` with `_` and make chars  all upper case

Comment: its OK for the first one, but for this one ? APP-KEY

Comment: Try the same replace `-` with `_` or remove the dash completely. I suggest a read of the reference guide which explains the binding. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't be better to define this variables when you package the app. ?

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Dspring.profiles.active=pebloc,war -DAPP-KEY=pebloc
```